# CollectionView live sorting callback

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, collectionviewsource, listcollectionview

I have a `TreeView` that uses a `ListCollectionView` with a custom `IComprarer` and live shaping to order its children.  When the currently selected `TreeViewItem` is re-sorted in the view, I'd like the `TreeView` to automatically scroll to the `TreeViewItem`'s new position.  However, I can't find a way to be notified when the `ListCollectionView` applies a new sort, and the behavior I want doesn't seem to be built into the `TreeViewControl`.

Is there a way I can be notified when the `ListCollectionView` recomputes its sort order?

Comment: But ListCollectionView should not apply a new sort without something hapening

Comment: You're right, I could tie into each item's `PropertyChanged` event and listen for changes, and listen for `CollectionChanged` events on the `TreeView`'s `ItemsSource` in order to attach/detach handlers to each item, but that's a lot of work.  Work that the `ListCollectionView` is already doing under the surface for me.  If I need to go through that much effort I may as well just skip the live shaping altogether and sort my list manually in the ViewModel.

Comment: @NathanFriend isn't that `CollectionChanged` should do what you want? Have you even tried handling that event?

Comment: The `CollectionChanged` callback isn't called on my `ItemsSource` since the sorting is only happening in the view.

Comment: @NathanFriend have you tried doing something like this `((ICollectionView)yourListCollectionView).CollectionChanged += handler;`?

Comment: That works!  Why can't I access the `CollectionChanged` event directly on the `ListCollectionView`?  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: @NathanFriend see my answer for the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the event `CollectionChanged` is what you need. You can do something like this:

```
((ICollectionView)yourListCollectionView).CollectionChanged += handler;
```

The reason we have to cast here is `CollectionChanged` is implemented as the member of `INotifyPropertyChanged` (`ICollectionView` inherits from this interface), source code here:

```
event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged
{
    add {
            CollectionChanged += value;
    }
    remove {
            CollectionChanged -= value;
    }
}
```

This implementation is ***explicit***. So the event is hidden from normal access as a public member. To expose that member, you can either cast the instance to `ICollectionView` or `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

. When implementing an interface explicitly, you have to explicitly cast the instance to that interface before being able to access the interface members.

Example about implementing interface:

```
public interface IA {
   void Test();
}
//implicitly implement
public class A : IA {
   public void Test() { ... }
}
var a = new A();
a.Test();//you can do this


//explicitly implement
public class A : IA {
   void IA.Test() { ... } //note that there is no public and the interface name 
                          // is required
}
var a = new A();
((IA)a).Test(); //this is how you do it.
```